# Using AMD APP SDK with C#?

Tags: c#, c++, opencl, gpgpu

I have searched everywhere but couldn't find any definite information.
Are there any bindings or a support for using [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-tools-sdks/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) with C#?
I have seen that there is APARAPI for Java, does something similar exist for C#?

Main reason why I'm asking this is that I would like to try out HSA and hUMA features, but I don't want to waste time with C++.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I use OpenCL from C#"?

Comment: I know about OpenCL.Net and similar implementations but I don't think that using OpenCl 2.0 automatically enables HSA on HSA-compatible hardware. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: AFAIK there is no C# equivalent Aparapi.  Additionally, HSA features on AMD hardware are still in beta; a beta that only gets tested on a specific APU.

Comment: I planned on buying Kaveri APU, which is the first one that truly supports HSA so I wondered is there any C# support so I can quickly do simple prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this option 
[GpuLinq](https://github.com/nessos/GpuLinq/) It compiles  LINQ code from C# or F#  source to OpenCL.  This isn't a generic C# API, but executes LINQ in parallel.,

From their Github Web page

"GpuLinq's main mission is to democratize GPGPU programming through LINQ. The main idea is that we represent the query as an Expression tree and after various transformations-optimizations we compile it into fast OpenCL kernel code. In addition we provide a very easy to work API without the need of messing with the details of the OpenCL API."

F#  is  a better fit for parallel  programming on GPU's than C#, because is has parallel asynchronous patterns.

As of October 2014, HSA and hUMA are still very cutting edge. The Linux Kernel patch was in June 2014, Java support is coming in 2015, There may be problems with a  C#/F#  to OpenCL layered approach that are untested and untried with HSA.  So trying to use a higher-level programming  language may lead you to spend more time debugging infrastructure issues, than you would spend coding in C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

I found this: OpenCL.net .NET bindings for OpenCL that are easy-to-use and true to the original API. There is no OOP abstraction, nor will there ever be. OpenCL.Net is meant to be small, fast (with as little explicit marshaling as possible) and .NET friendly at the same time.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCL.Net/